# How to validate if an item is removed from picklist?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I need to verify if an item is able to me removed from selected items into the picklist. I've tryed using valueChangeListener but for some reason my method has not been called.
So i've tryed another way. I've used a4j:support with onlistchange event. With this one I get in server side, but only when i add items to my picklist. If I remove some item the method in server side to validate it is not called.

```
<rich:pickList value="#{home.instance.campos}" styleClass="pick_margin_fix" required="true"
                copyControlLabel="Selecionar" copyAllControlLabel="Selecionar Todos" removeAllControlLabel="Remover Todos"
                removeControlLabel="Remover"  >
                <a4j:support  event="onlistchanged" action="#{home.testeModificacao2}" ajaxSingle="true"/>
                <s:selectItems value="#{campoService.obterTodos()}" var="campo" label="#{campo.descricao}" noSelectionLabel="true"  />
                <s:convertEntity />
            </rich:pickList>
```

Someone knows what can be the problem?