# rich picklist + javascript validation

Tags: java, javascript, validation, richfaces

I am trying to use the richfaces component picklist with a javascript validation.

What I want to do is to call a javascript method on Add/Remove button pressed (this works fine), but I would like to be able to cancel its add or remove action.

For example I should be able to say : You try to remove an element called 'A' from the list, but you can't and then nothing should happen.

I can actually get the element to be removed or added, but even with the "onlistchanged" attribute i can not interrupt the add/remove action from picklist (e.g: JS validation shows, but element is still treated and moved to one or another list).

Do you have any idea if such a thing is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, i found a way to do that, not using richfaces though.

I added an event listener on the "Remove button" so that it can switch a global boolean variable to true.

Then using onlistchange attribute (not onlistchange** d** as it corresponds to the event coming after the list is updated (the documentation is not clear about that by the way, mixing up the names/description...)) i check if the value i want to remove is able to be removed (jQuery find selected element in list ...).

Be sure to write onlistchange="return yourFunctionThatDoesWhatever();" ... (return false will abort the add/remove effect)

[This question has been asked at least twice on this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582943/how-to-validate-if-an-item-is-removed-from-picklist#)

jav974